# Vim indentation and the prooftree package

Tags: vim, latex, indentation

I am using the fabulous vim-latex suite. I use (a lot) the prooftree package which has commands of the kind:

```
   \prooftree SOME-HYPOTHESIS-HERE
     \justifies SOME-CONCLUSION-HERE
     \using NAME-OF-RULE
   \endprooftree
```

My problem is that the automatic indentation for TeX files in vim for some reason does this:

```
   \prooftree SOME-HYPOTHESIS-HERE
   \justifies SOME-CONCLUSION-HERE
   \using NAME-OF-RULE
\endprooftree
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: A workaround is to use the proof package, which provides the \infer command, which is somehow similar (just in the opposite direction), but I would prefer to find a solution in general of how to add an indentation structure to VIM.

Comment: Thank you for deleting your identical question on SO; not many people are so tidy! (Unfortunately, I don't have an answer for you, but let's hope the audience here is distinct from SO, any you'll get lucky.)